# Scala Function Composition

Tags: scala, function

```
def t[A] = (l:List[A]) => l tail
def r[A] = (r:List[A]) => r reverse
def tr[A] :List[A] => List[A] = t compose r

tr(List(1,2,3,4))
```

> List(3, 2, 1)

As expected.

But somehow, every variant (with several variations of type annotations) I have tried on

```
def tr = tail compose reverse
```

fails (not found - value tail). I am missing something obvious, but I am stuck.

Comment: Where is tail coming from in your final code snippet?

Comment: The same tail (I thought) as in the first line - the tail of a traversable collection

Comment: tail is a method on a traversable. You can't start with tail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in scala, A => B will be treated as Function1 which define the method compose, so if u want to use tail compose reverse, you need to give scala compiler hint that what "**class**" it is, and then change a "**method**" to a "**function**".

the example :

`def tr[A] = ((x: List[A]) => x.tail) compose ((x: List[A]) => x.reverse)`

Answer (score 10):

Well let's start from the back, what `compose` function does.

It is defined in the [Function1](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Function1) as `def compose[A](g: (A) => T1): (A) => R`, and description

> Composes two instances of Function1 in a new Function1, with this function applied last.

What it does it takes another function `g`, taking parameter of some type - `A`, and returning same type `T1`. It creates new function which , when called is equivalent to call `f(g(x))`.

The two functions you have defined:

```
def t[A] = (l:List[A]) => l.tail
def r[A] = (r:List[A]) => r.reverse
```

They take no parameters, but return functions which take a list and call `tail` and `reverse` respectively on the argument.

The same you could write like:

```
def t[A](l: List[A]): List[A] = l.tail
def r[A](l: List[A]): List[A] = l.reverse
```

so the composition of two functions is `t(r(List(1,2,3,4)))`.

The `tail` or `reverse` however are not functions, they are method defined in a `List` class. They must be called on an object, and there is no way you could do `tail(reverse(arg))`.

Answer (score 2):

`compose` is a function (i.e. `Function1`) composition.

`List[T].tail` and `List[T].reverse` are `List[T]` **methods**